Might these two questions be good candidates for merging? (examples of all-solid-to-orbit)
Has there ever been a completely solid fuelled orbital rocket? +13 asked in 2021 received 5 answers before being closed as a duplicate of Do launchers using only solid propellant exist? +15 asked in 2018 with 4 answers.
While there is some overlap (my answers to each at least) I think there are some important answers to the newer closed question that should get just as much visibility as the older question.
One problem is that the older question begins

The question is restricted to launchers that have already been used to launch an object into orbit before today (April 2018).

which poses a problem - perhaps the closing of the newer question is actually problematic. For example, where can I post the answer that the Hyperola-1's "successful maiden flight was on 25 July 2019, at 05:00 UTC"?
I can't post this as an answer to the closed question, and the open question only allows systems successful by April 2018. Further, this date restriction has no significance now in 2024, and Stack Exchange is not only about writing good answers, but folks being able to find those good answers later!
And although in the main meta Have there been analyses to see if views of well-received answers are reduced by closure as duplicate which try to control for other factors? +10 has no answers (probably because it's challenging to measure objectively) I think that closure as duplicate has a risk of directing both human readers, and search engines & other non-human entities away from the closed question and therefore it's excellent answers.
Might these be a good candidate for merging?
Both question posts are short. In the body of the closed question, some additional questioning about cost exists, but the five answers are still primarily "here's another example of an all-solid-to-orbit system" which still nicely answer the still-open question.
So I wonder if this would be a particularly straightforward merge?
